# AutoComplete in Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, autocomplete, combobox

I'm pretty new to C#, and I'm working in VS 2010.
I'm trying to give a combobox autocomplete-properties.
I've googled around alot, and found that the most guides refere to a "AutoComplete" setting, in Properties, but I can't find that setting anywhere. (The "AutoComplete" not "Properties".)

I need to give my autocomplete-function some features: 
The autocomplete-list needs to be empty to begin with, and when a user enteres something that isn't in the list already, it should be added to the list.
So the autocomplete-list only contains strings which is already entered, and adds new entries to the list.

I figure this is some pretty basic code, but it seems I can't google myself to a useful guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If found out it is because I'm using WPF and not Windows.Forms.
In WPF it is the IsTextSearchEnabled setting that must be set to true.
In XAML it would look like this:

`<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" Width="170" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="true">

   <ComboBoxItem>aaad</ComboBoxItem>

    <ComboBoxItem>dddd</ComboBoxItem>

      <ComboBoxItem>eeed</ComboBoxItem>

 </ComboBox>`

Comment: Ah, next time, don't forget to mention WPF ;-) I assumed you were talking about Windows-Forms.

Comment: Yeah, I found out there's a difference. But thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the screen you're looking for:

[image: Visual Studio - Properties]

The AutoCompleteCustomSource, AutoCompleteMode and AutoCompleteSource properties are shown as you can see. This Properties Window can be opened with the shortcut **F4**.

Comment: Yeah @Rhapsody, that's the same guides I've googled, but I do not have the three "AutoComplete*" properties.
They simply aren't there.
I'm listing the properties alphabetically, and the only two I've got which starts with an A is "AllowDrop" and "AlternationCount".

Comment: Are you targetting .NET4? (Just a wild guess)

Comment: No that's ok. You can try to switch over to .NET 4 full, but I don't think that will change something. I thought maybe you're using .net 2.0 and those properties were possible introduced later. But at my IDE, the properties are available and I've used them in the past (.net 3.5)...

Comment: Nope, that didn't change a thing, but thanks anyway.
Any other ideas? =)

Comment: Unfortunately not, maybe you are able to post your solution?